# How does at low power factor impedance (p.f=R/Z) (if R is constant ) increases while current also increases?

Tags: impedance, power-factor-correction

Impedance is equivalent resistance of circuit having resistive and reactive components so if we keep R constant and increase inductance than Z will increase and power factor will going to decrease as power factor can also be stated as ratio of R and Z. (R/Z) 
 So here comes a contradiction that increasing impedance increasing the current.

Comment: Who says it does?

Comment: What do you mean by this. I am asking at low power factor current increases but as per formula p.f=V/Z the increase in impedance increases power factor.

Comment: Why do you say that increasing Z, increases current? Sure, R/Z decreases, but R/Z is not an impedance so doesn't feature in Ohm's law

Comment: R/Z decreases but if you keep resistive load constant then Z increases which follows decrease in R/Z. Suppose if i connect 100 W bulb with the wire having some inductance so the impedance would be Z=(R^2+Xj^2)^0.5 so if you keep R constant and increases X then Z increases which lowers the power factor.

Comment: You need to provide more information because as current increases, active power increases, but so does apparent power so we are back to ratios. What type of circuit are you referencing? Series RL, parallel RL, motor?

Answer (score 0):

> So here comes a contradiction that increasing impedance increasing the current.

This is wrong.  You cannot increase opposition and get more current.

$$I = \frac {V_S} {Z}$$

Ohm's Law is Ohm's Law, regardless of power factor.

Comment: Sorry to say but i think you miss the fact that at low power factor current increases. Because at low power factor more current is require to produce the require active power.

Comment: As power factor increases with R constant, impedance decreases and current increases.